# What is going on with these insuresaving.com sites

Tags: discussion

Today I came across this, during a web search:

http://unix.insuresaving.com

Is this some kind of clone?

Comment: Thanks, I have reported this.

Comment: http://unix.insuresaving.com/?tab=active has been nuked from orbit. Thanks for reporting!